# Wildcard mask and Subnet mask

Tags: networking, wildcard, mask, cisco, subnet

Im trying to understand wild card masks, here's an example of what I'm trying to do

*IP ADDRESS*: **192.168.1.1** = 11000000.10101000.00000001.00000001

*WILDCARD*  : **0.0.0.0**     = 00000000.00000000.00000000.00000000

***Result***    : **192.168.1.1** = 11000000.10101000.00000001.00000001

Does this mean that the only accepted address is 192.168.1.1 or does that mean its only blocking 192.168.1.1?

Comment: It depends on what you use it for, but that IP address with that wildcard mask will only match that exact IP address. Whether it's accepted or blocked, depends on what you're doing with it.

Answer (score -1):

in short:

IP is Accepted if it belongs to the network

the rule is:

```
HOST_IP   &   MASK   =    NETWORK
NETWORK   |  (~MASK) =    BRWDCAST

 - & stand for BITWISE AND
 - | stand for BITWISE OR
 - ~ stand for BITWISE NOT (reverse)
```

*if you plan to subnet your network, you have to be aware of Private and Public network, and reserved IP addresses.*